# How to specify that Nuxt don't clear out generation directory target in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a mini-app using Laravel and Nuxt.

My directory structure is organized as follows:

```
backend/ 
  ... LARAVEL FILES ... 
frontend/ 
  ... NUXT FILES ...
```

My `nuxt.config.js` has the following line

```js
{
   ...
   generate: {
     "dir": "../backend/public"
   }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to generate a Nuxt SPA into Laravel's `public` directory.

I'm use `yarn generate` to generate the files.

However, this clears out the entire `backend/public` directory and removes Laravel files.

```
robots.txt
index.php
favicon.ico
```

I don't want to remove these files since it's the `index.php` that loads Laravel I guess.

Is it possible to specify that Nuxt.js do not remove these three files and just output the folder there without deleting these three files.

My alternative option is to create a bash script which temporarily moves the three files on another directory - say `backend/build-temp` - and then copies them back to the `backend/public` after Nuxt generates the SPA. However, I think this will add another overhead to the building process. What do you think of this?